# How to change message "Invalid Date" in ngx bootstrap datepicker without being in node modules

Tags: angular, datepicker, locale, ngx-bootstrap

I changed the language of my datepicker but the message that appears is still in English. I know it is inside ngx-bootstrap / chronos / locale / locale.defaults.ts where it brings the following information

```
export declare const defaultInvalidDate = "Invalid date";
```

I would also like to change this message. Is there any information I have to add to the "input [bsConfig] =" ... Anyway, where can I change this message without moving the Node Modules folder? Thank you.

Comment: Hi. Did you manage to solve it out  ? we're facing the same issue. we need to apply different text according to a loaded locale.

Comment: NO... the problem persist. :(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I finally managed to do it :

You can import your `LocaleData` object and the function `defineLocale`:

```
import {enGbLocale} from 'ngx-bootstrap/locale';
import {BsLocaleService, defineLocale} from 'ngx-bootstrap';
```

Then, in your constructor you can access every attributes of `enGbLocale` and modify it:

```
constructor(private localeService: BsLocaleService) {
    enGbLocale.invalidDate = 'Custom label';
    defineLocale('custom locale', enGbLocale); 
    this.localeService.use('custom locale');
}
```

Comment: This I do where ... In the TS file of the page where I use the datepicker ... in the app.module.ts ??

Comment: Yes you do it in the component where you use the datepicker.

[Here's an example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-bootstrap-bsdatepicker-invaliddate)

Comment: @GuilhermeSester If you use the datepicker in more than one Component in your application I would recommend that you override the message in your `app.module.ts`

Answer (score 0):

Create an adapter to overwrite the default `BsDatepickerConfig` to a format that won't trigger an error

In the main module where you include your `BsDatePicker`

```
@NgModule({
  providers: [
    { provide: BsDatepickerConfig, useFactory: NaoDatepickerConfig },
    ....
  ]
}
```

`nao-date-picker.adapter.ts`

```
import { BsDatepickerConfig } from 'ngx-bootstrap/datepicker';

export function NaoDatepickerConfig(): BsDatepickerConfig {
  return Object.assign(new BsDatepickerConfig(), {
    dateInputFormat: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import { getLocale } from 'ngx-bootstrap/chronos';

const enLocale = getLocale();
enLocale.invalidDate = 'Custom label';
```

Comment: Please elaborate how your code solves thie issue.