# How to set custom date to bsdatepicker on bsValueChange

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

Trying to manipulate the selected date to show a different value to the user. Would like to include the start of the day, week, month. Same applies if it is the end.

This is what I am trying to achieve, say I select today's date and I want to display the start of the day for example: 31/05/2019 00:00:00 and for the end of the day 31/05/2019 23:59:59

I believe bsdatepicker does not provide that out of the box so I need to manipulate the date using moment and set it as a view value. It is limiting that bsValue only accepts a date and if you were to re-assign that during the (bsValueChange) output event. You get a maximum call stack error.

Trying to change this value using ngModel on change but the selected value of the user always takes precedence over the value that gets set to the ngModel variable.

```
<input ([ngModel])="myVar" bsDatepicker (bsValueChange)="onChange($event)">

public onChange(date: Date) {
  myVar = 31/05/2019 00:00:00 // ths will be overriden by the user's selected date which made think that 

this.datepicker.bsValue = 31/05/2019 00:00:00 //moment manipulated date - this will trigger a maximum callstack error.
}
```

This leaves me with the option of working directly with the DOM because I have tried all sorts with renderer2 (to maintain recommended approach and "security" by angular) but haven't been successful

Comment: Can you provide a stackblitz? Your code snippet is invalid `myVar = 31/05/2019 00:00:00` and `this.datepicker.bsValue = 31/05/2019 00:00:00`

Comment: @penleychan The code is trying to demonstrate the re-assigning of the variables / properties of the approaches I have tried and explained this in the discription. If stackblitz is required will try and recreate the issues I have come across.

I have an alternative, a lot simpler approach which i believe will work instead of trying to complicate things with render2 or elementRef (I don't think I need these just to simplay change a viewValue of an input). Will post some feedback if the approach gets me over the hurdle

Answer (score 0):

Managed to work around this issue by using the [value] attribute on the target input. Once the date is formatted to include unit of time. This formatted date value then gets set on the [value] attribute.

This then led to an unexpected issue where by if the date is cleared (empty string) this in turn makes the bsDatepicker to set an "Invalid Date" on the target input. To work around this I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50415568/how-to-change-message-invalid-date-in-ngx-bootstrap-datepicker-without-being-i)